# An "impossible" null returned reading files using Java IO

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I'm using a completion service to tell me when a group of files have been loaded successfully. 
This is the method that reads the file:

```
public static LocalDateColumn readLocalDateColumn(String fileName, ColumnMetadata metadata) throws IOException {
    LocalDateColumn dates = new LocalDateColumn(metadata);
    assert(dates != null);
    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
         SnappyFramedInputStream sis = new SnappyFramedInputStream(fis, true);
         DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sis)) {
      boolean EOF = false;
      while (!EOF) {
        try {
          int cell = dis.readInt();
          dates.add(cell);
        } catch (EOFException e) {
          EOF = true;
        }
      }
    }
    //System.out.println(dates);
    return dates;
  }
```

Note that dates is assigned a value in the first statement that is checked by an assertion.  Also note the second to last line: The commented out print statement. When this statement is **not** commented out, the return value is never null. When it is commented out, it's null about 1/2 the time running on the same data.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

BTW. The use of EOF exception-catching to find the end of the file looks ugly, but is required by Snappy for correct operation. I've used it in other code and it has always worked fine.

FWIW, The code above is called using a CompletionService
It looks like this:

```
List<Column> columnList = new ArrayList<>();
try {
  for (ColumnMetadata column : columnMetadata) {
    readerCompletionService.submit(() -> {
      columnList.add(readColumn(path + File.separator + column.getId(), column));
      return null;
    });
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < columnMetadata.size(); i++) {
    Future future = readerCompletionService.take();
    future.get();
  }
  for (Column c : columnList) {
    columns.put(c.id(), c);
  }
```

At the point where execution reaches the last line. That is:

```
columns.put(c.id(), c);
```

c is sometimes null.

Comment: When println (which is a synchronised method) changes your concurrent program, the likely conclusion is that there is a race condition, that gets solved/hidden by the extra synchronisation.

Comment: do you actually run your java runtime with assertions enabled (`-ea` argument to java executable) ?

Comment: For example, columnList is used concurrently although ArrayList is not thread safe...

Comment: @Andre Holzner. Yes. -ea was enabled.

Comment: @assylias That's a good catch. I will replace with a thread-safe collection and retry.

Comment: @assylias Changing the collection worked. If you write your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an `ArrayList` concurrently but that collection is not thread safe. You should try to use a thread safe collection instead, such as a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.